# RETS MLS Search

Tags: asp.net, rets

How to get data from RETS service?

I want to integrate services in ASP.Net.. is there any sdk available for it?

http://matrixrets.abor.com/rets/search.ashx?Class=ResidentialProperty&SearchType=PropertyQueryType=DMQL2&%20Format=COMPACT&StandardNames=1&Query=(ST=|ACT,SOLD)&Count=2

Above is my service query I am trying and I tried lots of other parameters but always setting some error code every time.

For ASP.Net if any dll who works with RETS or any better document on it how search query should be written it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The MLS "system" is very much "local" and as I discovered myself, a shambles with no agreed standard. When you say local, where are you talking about? In California, you can use the ezRETS ODBC driver:

http://www.crt.realtors.org/projects/rets/ezrets/

Check out the CRT Center for Realtor Technology:
http://www.crt.realtors.org/

Comment: Yes, thx.I am using libRETS for .net and now facing different search query syntax types. From where can I find diff. query parts for rets search?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "query parts"?

Comment: SearchRequest searchRequest = session.CreateSearchRequest(                                        "Property",                                                         "RESI",                                                             "(ListPrice=300000+)");

Comment: Currently I passed list price condition - I am confused about other conditions and query parts .. how to write? how we know that which conditions are there? There is no proper documentation on rets.org as well.

Comment: I think only your realtor will be able to get this information for you.

Comment: He'll have to get the info from his local realtor board.

Answer (score -1):

MLS IDX Feed Data Download API Available

http://www.reso.org/developer-resources

You can setup in ASP.NET,Java,PHP

Suggestion use PHRETS API for IDX better way to implement easy

More detail we can discuss skype :shailesh.makwana990